# Overflow not allowing js to hide element with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have header tag that when scrolling down it will hide it. But because i want to use parallax layers with overflow, i'm not able to do so, the header just gets stuck on the screen and moves with other elements same direction.

If you disable Overflow in css you will see that the effect is working, but then by disabling Overflow i'm losing parallax effect.

```js
var $content = $('.box');

window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function Scroller() {
  this.latestKnownScrollY = 0;
  this.ticking = false;
};

Scroller.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), false);
  },

  onScroll: function() {
    this.latestKnownScrollY = window.scrollY;
    this.requestTick();
  },

  requestTick: function() {
    if (!this.ticking) {
      window.requestAnimFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
    this.ticking = true;
  },

  update: function() {
    var currentScrollY = this.latestKnownScrollY;
    this.ticking = false;

    var slowScroll = currentScrollY / 2
    var opaScroll = 1.4 - currentScrollY / 200
    $content.css({
      'transform': 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      '-moz-transform': 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      'opacity': opaScroll
    });

  }
};

var scroller = new Scroller();
scroller.init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /*   left: 50%; */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*   margin-left: -1500px; */
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: rgb(199, 27, 187);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* left: 20%; */
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
  /* position: fixed; */
  z-index: 14;
  /* left: 20px;
      right: 20px; */
  line-height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -1px #000000bf;
  /* left: 80%; */
}

.section_dark {
  background-color: #282e34;
  color: #ddd;
}

header .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

header text-box {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: .5em 3em .2em 3em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 2em;
}

header h1,
header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3rem;
  background-color: #282e34;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Firewatch Parallax in CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png" />
    </div>

    <header>
      <div class="box">
        <text-box>
          <h1>Test</h1>
        </text-box>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__cover">
      <section class="section section_dark">
        <h2>Section One</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, laudantium, quibusdam? Nobis, delectus, commodi, fugit amet tempora facere dolores nisi facilis consequatur, odio hic minima nostrum. Perferendis eos earum
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happen is when add overflow it add scroll to div `parallax` not to `window` to check change css class `parallax height:1000px` and you will notice that you have 2 scroll check the link below added in CodePen  So the change it back and added `id="par"` in div `parallax` also change in JS Script from `window` to document.getElementById('par')  and also in side `onScroll: function()` change from `window.scrollY` to `document.getElementById('par').scrollTop`

[Link](https://codepen.io/ockba/pen/BGxaER/)

By the way excellent Idea

```js
      var $content = $('.box');

  document.getElementById('par').requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return document.getElementById('par').requestAnimationFrame ||
  document.getElementById('par').webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
  document.getElementById('par').mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
     window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function Scroller() {
  this.latestKnownScrollY = 0;
  this.ticking = false;
};

Scroller.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    document.getElementById('par').addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), false);
  },

  onScroll: function() {
    this.latestKnownScrollY =  document.getElementById('par').scrollTop;
    this.requestTick();
  },

  requestTick: function() {
    if (!this.ticking) {
    document.getElementById('par').requestAnimFrame(this.update.bind(this));
    }
    this.ticking = true;
  },

  update: function() {
    var currentScrollY = this.latestKnownScrollY;
    this.ticking = false;    
    var slowScroll = currentScrollY / 2
    var opaScroll = 1.4 - currentScrollY / 200
    $content.css({
      'transform': 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      '-moz-transform': 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(' + slowScroll + 'px)',
      'opacity': opaScroll
    });

  }
};

var scroller = new Scroller();
scroller.init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.parallax {
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  /*   left: 50%; */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*   margin-left: -1500px; */
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: rgb(199, 27, 187);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* left: 20%; */
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}

.section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 80px;
  /* position: fixed; */
  z-index: 14;
  /* left: 20px;
      right: 20px; */
  line-height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px -1px #000000bf;
  /* left: 80%; */
}

.section_dark {
  background-color: #282e34;
  color: #ddd;
}

header .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

header text-box {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: .5em 3em .2em 3em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 2em;
}

header h1,
header h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.text {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3rem;
  background-color: #282e34;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 0 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Firewatch Parallax in CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="par" class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png" />
    </div>

    <header>
      <div class="box">
        <text-box>
          <h1>Test</h1>
        </text-box>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
      <img src="https://sam.beckham.io/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__cover">
      <section class="section section_dark">
        <h2>Section One</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, laudantium, quibusdam? Nobis, delectus, commodi, fugit amet tempora facere dolores nisi facilis consequatur, odio hic minima nostrum. Perferendis eos earum
        </p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```